# Git does not exit cleanly (exit code 1) when I try to commit Visual C# Project file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, github, tortoisegit

I have my ASP.NET MVC Project Repository in GitHub.
By using Git Extensions I have taken the Clone into my local machine. I have added new Folders / .cs files / .aspx files etc.

I have Committed all the new files using TortoiseGit Commit by Right Clicking on each folder/files successfully.

Since I have added new files/folders, then I have to commit the Project file (*.csproj), when I try to commit I got the error:

> "did not exit cleanly (exit code 1).

What can I do now? should I open the Project file directly in GitHub repository and update it from my local directory project file? like, copy and Paste! 
It will provide any issue later on! let me know if any have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the file is taken by another process: try the same commit after closing other windows.

If not, check also the command-line alternative, after installing a [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (2.21 at the moment)

Comment: now the file is marked as green right mark, i can't commit again,but in GitHub it is not updated. looks like some place in the local committed.

Comment: @AdithyaM To reset locally, you can try a `git rm folder` (no trailing slash), with `folder` being the name of the subtree folder. Commit. Then try again the subtree command, commit and push.